# replace function- No overload for this method takes 2 arguments

Tags: c#

I am trying to perform a string replace, but it results in:"No overload for method Replace accepts 2 arguments."

What I need to do:
fetch string(usernames) separated by "." and store only the 1st half.

input can be eu.rails.io or in.rails.io, or fr.rails.io

desired result eu, in, fr

`geo = geo.Replace(".rails.io", "");`

(declared this variable geo earlier)

//results in error— "No overload for the method Replace takes 2 arguments"

(edited with 'geo'var)

Comment: `var` is a reserved word for C#. Don't use it as the variable name.

Comment: i don't see what datatype 'var' is supposed to be in your code-snippet (it should be 'string'), also var is a bad name for a variable because thats already reserved as keyword in c#. And from what i understand what you are trying to do you should instead take a look at string.split()

Comment: In fact, `var` is an "contextual keyword" (recognized as keyword only if it is in the expected place) so this should not be the problem.

Comment: `var geo = geo.Anything();` wouldn't work because `geo` is clearly already declared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: If the `Replace` Method has an error, the variable `geo` might not be a string.

Multiple possibilities. You could replace the part `".rails.io"` as you suggested:

```
string geo = "eu.rails.io";
geo = geo.Replace(".rails.io", string.Empty);
```

You could also split the string at the point, and only use the first part (you need to be sure, that the string you want to keep doesn't contain a dot):

```
string geo = "eu.rails.io";
geo = geo.Split('.')[0];
```

Comment: Thanks Jeanot, however I am still getting an error. eg- I did— var geo = json.Getvalue("company"); geo = geo.Split('.')[0]; return geo;. error is —JToken does not contain a definition for Split. Do I need to cast geo as string?

Comment: maybe `json.Getvalue<string>("company")`

Comment: That explains your problem. Your `geo` variable is not a string but a `JToken`. I assume you can get the value of your Token somehow. I have no experience with JToken, but it might be as simple as `var geo = json.Getvalue("company").Value<string>();` or a call to `ToString()`. These are just guesses though.